# Change backgroung-size using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I am working in jquery mobile and my background is image.Due to the different mobile screen sizes my images does not coves my full screen.It is possible only if this script works.

```
document.getElementById("pageone").style.backgroundSize = screen.width+"px" screen.height+"px";
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can CSS for this.

```
html { 
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../images/bg_cover_web.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: i am using this.this helps in height but not covering the whole width

Comment: Make sure that your div that you are using is height: 100%; and width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a percentage width?

I haven't used jQuery mobile, but I have found that meta tags are important for responsive design: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag